Bathroom Mirror Mount: How to Fix
I have a swivel mirror in my bathroom which one day decided to detach from the mount hardware.  I can't for the life of me identify how it is supposed to be connected or if something maybe broke that I didn't see.  The mirror has been mounted for at least 7 years and not had any issue.
In this first photo, at the top, you can see where the mirror hardware is supposed to mount to the wall.  The knob between the zip ties is supposed to "connect" the the U shaped hook attached to the wall.  When I line the two up, they are just short of each other and won't connect.  The "knob" is removable and has a set screw in it, but the set screw doesn't seem to tighten around the U hook.
Wonder if anyone knows how something like this is typically installed, if I'm maybe missing a piece.  Appreciate any help or insight!








what brand name is the mirror?

@jsotola - I haven't seen a single marking on any piece.  No brand, model, anything.

I wonder if that bushing is supposed to be basically crimped over the end of that gooseneck, and the fit just came out of tolerance.

does the gooseneck slide downward inside the wall mount?

@jsotola - The gooseneck doesn't slide and is in place by a screw on the reverse side of the plate.  It can only mount in that one position.

@Huesmann - In the 2nd photo, you can see the gooseneck is a bit shiny and is where the set screw would maybe land on it, which makes me wondering if that's where it landed previously.  I've tried just tried to get the bushing to stay there, but it doesn't adhere at all.
